# Actualizar tabla de datagriedview al actualizar la base de datos

Tags: c#, sql-server

El caso es el siguiente, el codigo insertado abajo registra un la entrada/salida de un empleado y al hacerlo la base de datos de la **`datagridview`** lo recibe y lo refleja, el problema es que al hacer lo anterior el datagridview no actualiza la tabla visible a pesar de que recibió un nuevo dato...espero su ayuda gracias

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open && txtID.Text.Length>9)
        {
            string q = "insert into Main(ID,Horario,EntSal)values('"+txtID.Text.ToString()+"','"+datet.Text.ToString()+"','"+ensal.Text.ToString()+"')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                txtID.Text = "";
                MainTable.Refresh();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empleado no encontrado en la base de datos", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txtID.Text = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola, indica por favor el código del datagridview en tu Form. Estás trabajando con Windows Forms no?

Comment: Listo @RafaelAcosta

Comment: listo ya indique el codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tu `DataGridView` refleje los cambios después de añadir un nuevo registro, debes volver a asignar los nuevos datos al `DataSource` del `DataGridView`.

Seria algo así:

```
MainTable.DataSource = Main("SELECT * FROM Main");
MainTable.Refresh();
```